# When comparing two boolean series in a pandas dataframe, how to return a new series including all NA from the previous two and favoring True values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I've been trying to solve a problem, which is to get the 'desired_final' column from the manipulation of 'before' and 'after' columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'before': pd.Series([True, True, True, False, False, False, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA], dtype='boolean'),
    'after': pd.Series([False, True, pd.NA, True, False, pd.NA, False, True, pd.NA], dtype='boolean'),
    'desired_final': pd.Series([True, True, True, True, False, False, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA], dtype='boolean')
})
```

[image]

Basically we are favoring True, unless before + after is False, or one of them is NA.

Finally thought of this, I think, hacky solution, but I'm hesitant to put it into prod.

```
def hack_solution(before_series, after_series):
    output_series = before_series.replace(True, pd.NA) + after_series
    return output_series.fillna(before_series)
```

I've also tried this on a friend's suggestion:

```
def possible_solution(before_series, after_series):
    res = []
    for x,y in zip(before_series, after_series):
        if pd.isnull(x): 
            res.append(pd.NA)
        elif x==True | y==True:
            res.append(True)
        else:
            res.append(x)
    return res

# Result:
# [True, True, True, False, False, False, <NA>, <NA>, <NA>] dtype: object
```

So two questions:

1. Why does possible_solution return an object and hack_solution a boolean?
2. And why does the possible_solution return False instead of True in index 3?

Comment: for question 1: you are returning a list from possible_solution (i.e., not a boolean). Each value in the list is a boolean.

Comment: `x == True or y==True`

Comment: Why do you consider the first solution hacky?

Answer (score 1):

For `possible_solution`, you need to wrap them in a bracket:

```
False == True | True == True
# False

(False == True) | (True == True)
# True
```

You can directly use `pandas.Series.fillna`:

```
desired = df["before"] + df["after"].fillna(df["before"])
print(desired)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     <NA>
7     <NA>
8     <NA>
dtype: boolean
```

Comment: Or `(df['before']+df['after']).fillna(df['before'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df['desired'] = (df[['before','after']].fillna(False)
                    .any(axis=1)
                    .where(df['before'].notna(), pd.NA)
                )
```

Hope it's self explained.